# Traffic light while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to kind of emulate a traffic light. However, once it gets to red, it does not loop back to green even though the value is zero. I have tried adding continue near the end but it does not loop back to original, why?

```
while True:
    if stop_light <10:
        print ("Green")
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light <20:
        print ("Yellow")
        stop_light +=1
    elif stop_light <30:
        print ("Red")
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light == 31:
        stop_light = 0
```

I have tried adding continue here, but still does not loop back to green, why?

Comment: ooh, wasn't sure if it came out correctly. On my screen, it looked like a blob of text with no indentions.

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
elif stop_light < 30:
    print ("Red")
    stop_light += 1
```

will only run up to and including when `stop_light` equals 29 and adding 1 on 29 will turn it to 30 and so it will never be 31. To fix this you need to change the `<` to `<=`, which means less than **or equal to**, or change 30 to 31.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is already explained above, it is not a good practice to compare the value of a number to constant which may cause the loops to stuck in unexpected results
Below should work, try this:

```
while True:
    if stop_light <10:
        print ("Green")
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light <20:
        print ("Yellow")
        stop_light +=1
    elif stop_light <30:
        print ("Red")
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light >= 30:
        stop_light = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have correctly highlighted your issue: missing the value of 30 in your if-checks.  For completeness, I'll repeat it here as the direct answer to your question:

As regards integers, the opposite of "Less Than" (`<`) is not "Greater Than" (`>`).  The opposite is "Greater than or Equal Two" (`>=`).  So your last condition could be the opposite of the previous condition:

```
... 
elif stop_light <30:
    print ("Red")
    stop_light += 1
elif stop_light >= 30:
    stop_light = 0
```

However, given the simplicity of this loop, you should consider learning techniques to discern *where* the problem is, and what variables (or other) do not match up with your mental understanding of the program.  This is the larger lesson to learn from your question.

I ask rhetorically, first, before giving a possible answer, "What did you do -- what steps did you take -- to debug the program, other than running it and seeing that results were not as you expected?"  One thing I might have tried:

> introspect (see) the value of `stop_light` at every iteration.  Perhaps `print("stop_light: ", stop_light)`

Learning coding is as much learning how to debug as it is semantics and logic of the problem.

Comment: Nah, it was more like me messing around to try and solidify while loop concepts. I'm self-teaching myself python at the moment and was trying to find some cool real-life examples and come up with that. Can you explain what debugging is tho? I have only recently begun self-teaching in my spare time.

Comment: Debugging? Start with [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).  But a short _hunteke_ summary: finding (and fixing) the errors in a program.  Succesful debugging boils down to knowing the state of your algorithm (in this case, the `stop_light` variable).